Modifying default theme column_right menu in OpenCart 3.0.4
OpenCart provides more default features than I wish to offer my users. My current challenge is how to remove menu entries such as "Recurring payments" and "Downloads" from the default menu that is populated by the column_right.twig template file.
The code in view/theme/default/template/common/column_right.twig is:
{% if modules %}
<aside id="column-right" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
  {% for module in modules %}
  {{ module }}
  {% endfor %}
</aside>
{% endif %}

I presume that the menu entries are populated by iterating over the collection called modules, but I have not been able to find where the modules collection is initialised.
I can't find a way to control initialisation from the admin portal. And I've not worked out how to control initialisation by modifying the underlying code.
Any help would be appreciated.

view/theme/default/template/account/account.twig
Line No. 38
Line No. 42

Thanks - that helped. I ended up changing lots of twig files :)

i think by checking design/layout from admin panel
you can check which modules are injected in column_right in every page
